# Choosing your angular version

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to this stuff, i was wondering, im developing an app using Ionic, and the current version o angular i'm using is 4. Suppose i want to use angular 1, how can i do that? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to use angularjs (version < 2)? It is usually recommended to go for the latest stable version. Which is 4 right now

Comment: Angular 1 and Angular 2+ are completely different frameworks (to the point where I think they probably shouldn't have kept the same name). If you want to use Angular 1, you'd have to switch to Ionic 1 and rewrite most of your app. That said... don't. Angular 1 is awful and outdated and I wouldn't wish it on anyone.

Comment: As for the name, I saw that often people uses _AngularJS_ when they refers to version 1 and simply _Angular_ for 2+ versions. But yes, they could be more specific..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ionic just released new client (v3, a few days ago) so according to docs
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli

```
$ npm install -g ionic@latest
$ ionic start myNewProject blank --type ionic1
$ cd ./myNewProject
$ ionic serve
```

*BUT* 
ionic1 (angular1 based) is really outdated ...

- scopes (including rootscope) and 'easy' two-way binding beetween components are no longer supported
- ionic is typescript based now